# What is the purpose of the Frame class in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code below will build a basic buttons GUI

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
  def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.button = Button(frame, 
                         text="QUIT", fg="red",
                         command=quit)
    self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.slogan = Button(frame,
                         text="Hello",
                         command=self.write_slogan)
    self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)
  def write_slogan(self):
    print("Tkinter is easy to use!")

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But even when i get the Frame class off and replace it with master it shows the same results!

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
  def __init__(self, master):
    #frame = Frame(master)
    #frame.pack()
    self.button = Button(master, 
                         text="QUIT", fg="red",
                         command=quit)
    self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.slogan = Button(master,
                         text="Hello",
                         command=self.write_slogan)
    self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)
  def write_slogan(self):
    print("Tkinter is easy to use!")

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Why is it so important to add the Frame class if we are going te get the same results anyway?

Comment: Do you see the difference if in your first example if you pack with padding? `frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)`. There are packing properties that are useful for a collection of widgets, which a frame simply contains for you.

Comment: Tried it, i will keep it in mind. Thanks @RonNorris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it so important to add the Frame class if we are going to get the same results anyway?

In your specific example, there is no point in creating a frame.

> What is the purpose of the Frame class in Tkinter?

The purpose is to act as a container for a group of widgets that you want to treat as a logical unit.

For example, a traditional app might have a toolbar across the top, a navigation panel to the left, a main area, and perhaps a statusbar at the bottom. You might use a frame to contain all of the widgets in the toolbar, another frame for all of the widgets in the statusbar, and another frame to contain the widgets in the navigation pane.

Answer (score 0):

Frames are used for complex layouts. They help with grouping widgets into specific locations without having to manage the layout of ever widget directly for any basic layout changes.

There is some documentation on the use of Frames [HERE](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm).

If you are just creating a simple interface that does not require many widgets it may not be needed to use frames.

In the case of a more complex interface you may wish to use frames to promote better manageability of your layout.

One example: If you have a set of widgets set up on the right side of your screen but later decide you would prefer them to be on the left side of the screen you could just change the placement of the frame and all the widgets inside will move with it. If you did not use frames then you would need to change every widget configs to accomplish the same move. Far more work then using a frame to begin with.

That is just a simple example but it should illustrate why frames are very useful for layouts of your GUI.

You can also use frames as a way to decorate your GUI. You can layer a frame on top of an image and change the background of the frame to a contrasting color to make your GUI more visually appealing. You can use a frame as a separator line according to the linked documentation but I have not used it myself this way.

I would say there are many more ways a frame can be used in Tkinter and they provide better flexibility with GUI design then just using the root window alone.

Comment: Thank you Sierra, seems like you are an expert at this. What kind of resources you were after?

Comment: @Belle I am by no means an expert. I only started programming in February. I have spent 2 to 4 hours a day programming since then and a lot of that time has been spent using tkinter. What do you mean by "What resources I am after"?

Comment: That is an amazing progress! You are doing wonderful. I started in April 19 with an average of two and a half hour a day and as you can tell still struggling :( . By resources i mean Where do you get your knowledge from?

Comment: I think you are asking what resources I used to study. For that the first week I completcompleted the python course at codecadamy.com. Then I spent some time writing my own note taking program getting help here on stack overflow when I needed it.  But 80-90% of my learning has been from helping people on stack overflow. I find a new question and do some googling, then I try to write something that works on my end. If I can get a good answer going I try to make sure I know why my answer works then I post my answer. For me the best way to learn is to help others with their problems.

Comment: Wish you all the best. One final question, what is your goal of learning programming languages ?

Comment: I am a network engineer by trade and I have a decent resume, however I wanted to learn programming to round off my IT skill set. One of my other goals is to maybe write my own game one day though that is some time down the road I am sure. Just keep plugging away and you will eventually hit that "ah ha" moment :)

Comment: Computer networking is my major too 8), i am learning python to build up my resume and to build a social media app:-), hope your goals and wishes become a reality ;)